# Django. Admin's template dissapeared after moving into online hosting

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

It is a very strange situation but after I put my django website online... Django admin template dissapeared :( Everything is all right with website template but there is a problem with admin site

[It seems to be ok here](http://sghsgh.idl.pl/article/show_all/)

[But if you go to admin section...](http://sghsgh.idl.pl/admin/login/?next=/admin/)

How can I fix this problem? I searched admin files in my django project but there are no templates files for admin site.

What could happend on the hosting server? Can I fix it?

Comment: You need to collect static files. `./manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with the template, but with the static assets eg the CSS.

Comment: I found that I need to put into settings.py such lines STATIC_ROOT = "app-root/repo/wsgi/static"

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('assets', 'app-root/repo/wsgi/openshift/static'),

    ) Could you tell me please how can I find "app-root" path? because when I give this path I get an error: No such file or directory: '/home/sghsgh/aplikacja/app-root/repo/wsgi/openshift/static'

Answer (score 0):

You need to collects the static files into STATIC_ROOT. Run:

```
./manage.py collectstatic
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic

Comment: Should I do it in the shell? (venv)[sghsgh@s36:: ~/aplikacja ]:$ sudo ./manage.py collectstatic I get from my shell "command not found" :(

Comment: In the same way you run your Django development server. `python manage.py collectstatic` maybe?

Comment: but I don't know the path to this Static files.  I found something like this in the Internet but it doesn't work "app-root/repo/wsgi/static"

Comment: Tomasz... in production debug should be turned off... ;). Serving static files goes like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/